# Copying selected table repeatedly when clicking button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a repeated copy and paste of a table I have in one of my worksheets and assign it to buttons in my budget worksheet.

For example whenever you click on the contract button, it will install the new table. Click it again, it will leave a line break and insert the new table. Same thing with the variation button.

Budget worksheet
[image: Budget worksheet]

Table sample
[image: Table sample]

My attempt in a related copied sample in one of the questions asked here.
[image: screenshot 3]

I understand to copy and paste I've been told to use this code

```
Sub CopyPasteToAnotherSheet()
    Worksheets("Dataset").Range("B2:F9").Copy Worksheets("CopyPaste").Range("B2")
End Sub
```

It works, but I can only copy it once. I don't know how to copy it numerous times each time I run the macro.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please [edit] and include the code in the question itself as text formatted as code block.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack!

So I think I understand the want, it's usually good to have a go and show us the code you have but as its the first time here's a start of a code that might do that:

```
Sub variations()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Variations").Range("A1:B5")
    Run copyAcross(rng)
End Sub

Sub contracts()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Contract").Range("A1:B2")
    Run copyAcross(rng)
End Sub

Function copyAcross(rng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget")
    targetRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
    ws.Cells(targetRow, "A").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
End Function
```

this gives two subs that the buttons can be pointed to.  In each sub you can define the range you want and the function will copy it across.

Note:  for this to work column A in the Budget file would need at least some value somewhere in it, the first copy would then be put two rows below that